# Return XML structure up to the n-th level

Tags: xml, linux, xslt, xpath, xquery

Is there a simple way, possibly with open-source command line tools in Linux, to strip all levels beyond a given threshold from a given XML document, regardless of the structure?

Input:

```
<a att="1">
   <b/>
   <c bat="2">
      <d/>
   </c>
</a>
```

Output, level=1:

```
<a att="1"/>
```

Output, level=2:

```
<a att="1">
   <b/>
   <c bat="2"/>
</a>
```

I have tried XPath but was unable to restrict the level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple in XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::*) &lt;= $level">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Works for me after adding a `<xsl:stylesheet ...>` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

In XQuery it's almost the same as in XSLT:

```
copy $output := $input
modify delete nodes $output//node()[count(ancestor::*) eq $level]
return $output
```

[try it with zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#wvpJsujW71mBn9MIuCNKM0h9Bbk=)

Answer (score 2):

Or without XQuery Update, deconstruct and put together the tree again until the maximum level is reached:

```
declare function local:limit-level($element as element(), $level as xs:integer) {  
    if ($level gt 0)
    then
        element {node-name($element)} {
            $element/@*,
      (
        for $child in $element/node()  
        return local:limit-level($child, $level - 1)
      )
    }
  else ()
};

local:limit-level(/*, 2)
```